# Python - replay values in list

Tags: python, list

Please help for task with the list in Python my logic is bad works:( .

> This is full text of task: Write a program that takes a list of
>   numbers on one line and displays the values in a single row, are
>   repeated in it more than once.
>
> To solve the problem can be useful sort method list.
>
> The procedure for withdrawal of repetitive elements may be arbitrary.

My beginning code is :

```
st = (int(i) for i in input().split())
ls = []
for k in st:
    if k == k + 1 and k > 1:
```

Task is : if we have replay value in list we must print it. We only can use sort() method and without any modules importing.

Results Examples:

**Sample Input 1:**
4 8 0 3 4 2 0 3
**Sample Output 1:**
0 3 4
**Sample Input 2:**
10
**Sample Output 2:**

**Sample Input 3:**
1 1 2 2 3 3
**Sample Output 3:**
1 2 3

This code isn't run( sort() function doesn't want sort my_list. But I must input values like **my_list = (int(k) for k in input().split())**

```
st = list(int(k) for k in input())
st.sort()
for i in range(0,len(st)-1):
    if st[i] == st[i+1]:
        print(str(st[i]), end=" ")
```

Comment: I don't think that's what the OP is trying to do.  The OP needs to 'look ahead' in the list while iterating over it, in order to check "if next value == current value + 1". This might be useful: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate

Comment: Ah i see. But then the 1st example output makes no sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
my_list = (int(k) for k in input().split())
```

After running this line, `my_list` is a *generator*, something that will create a sequence - but hasn't yet done so. You can't sort a generator. You either need to use `[]`:

```
my_list = [int(k) for k in input().split()]
my_list.sort()
```

which makes `my_list` into a list from the start, instead of a generator, or:

```
my_list = list(int(k) for k in input().split()))
my_list.sort()
```

gather up the results from the generator using `list()` and then store it in my_list.

Edit: for single digits all together, e.g. 48304, try `[int(k) for k in input()]`. You can't usefully do this with split().

Edit: for printing the results too many times: make the top of the loop look backwards a number, like this, so if it gets to the second or third number of a repeating number, it skips over and continues on around the loop and doesn't print anything.

```
for i in range(0,len(st)-1):
    if st[i] == st[i-1]:
        continue
    if st[i] == st[i+1]:
        print...
```

Comment: Thanks it is work. But how I can input values like 48304 without using space. When I input values I use the space 4 8 3 0 4 and it is work. I must use like this 48304 - and it convert to 4 8 3 0 4

Comment: `st = list(int(k) for k in input())
st.sort()
for i in range(0,len(st)-1):
    if st[i] == st[i+1]:
        print(str(st[i]), end=" ")` - It is not work for value 465456464654

Comment: You haven't said what's wrong, but I've guessed what it could be, and updated my answer again.

Comment: Thanks all workd fine with this full code: `st = input().split()
st.sort()
for i in range(0, len(st)-1):
    if st[i] == st[i - 1]:
        continue
    if st[i] == st[i + 1]:
        print(str(st[i]), end=" ")
`

Answer (score 0):

```
st = (int(i) for i in input().split())
used = []
ls = []
for k in st:
    if k in used: # If the number has shown up before:
        if k not in used: ls.append(k) # Add the number to the repeats list if it isn't already there
    else:
        used.append(k) # Add the number to our used list
print ' '.join(ls)
```

In summary, this method uses two lists at once. One keeps track of numbers that have already shown up, and one keeps track of second-timers. At the end the program prints out the second-timers.

Comment: You should change `used` to be a `set`, also I'm assuming you mean `if k in used` not `if k in temp`.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But I can't use ' '.join(ls), because my task use only sort()

Comment: @EldarNecefov So you can't use `int` then either, or `input`? or `split`?

Comment: @EldarNecefov be clear about the rules... you already used `split` in your code

Comment: @AdamSmith I can use it : st = (int(i) for i in input().split())

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably make a set to keep track of what you've seen, and start appending to a list to keep track of the repeats.

```
lst = [num for num in input("prompt ").split()]
s = set()
repeats = []

for num in lst:
    if num in s and num not in repeats:
        repeats.append(num)
    s.add(num)

print ' '.join(map(str,repeats))
```

Note that if you don't need to maintain order in your output, this is faster:

```
lst = [num for num in input("prompt ").split()]
s = set()
repeats = set()
for num in lst:
    if num in s:
        repeats.add(num)
    s.add(num)

print ' '.join(map(str, repeats))
```

Although if you can use imports, there's a couple cool ways to do it.

```
# Canonically...
from collections import Counter
' '.join([num for num,count in Counter(input().split()).items() if count>1])
# or...
from itertools import groupby
' '.join([num for num,group in groupby(sorted(input().split())) if len(list(group))>1])
# or even...
from itertools import tee
lst = sorted(input('prompt ').split())
cur, nxt = tee(lst)
next(nxt) # consumes the first element, putting it one ahead.
' '.join({cur for (cur,nxt) in zip(cur,nxt) if cur==nxt})
```

Comment: I can't use in the task set() method and join() only use sort()

Comment: @EldarNecefov `set` is a function, not a method

Comment: `my_list = (int(k) for k in input().split())
my_list.sort()
for i in range(0,len(my_list)-1):
    if my_list[i] == my_list[i+1]:
        print(str(my_list[i]), end=" ") 
`

Answer (score 0):

this gives the answers you're looking for, not sure if it's exactly the intended algorithm:

```
st = (int(i) for i in input().split())
st = [i for i in st]
st.sort()
previous = None
for current in st:
    if ((previous is None and current <= 1)
            or (previous is not None and current == previous + 1)):
        print(current, end=' ')
    previous = current

>>> "4 8 0 3 4 2 0 3"
0 3 4
>>> "10"

>>> "1 1 2 2 3 3"
1 2 3
```

updated to:

- start with `st = (int(i) for i in input().split())`
- use only `sort` method, no other functions or methods... except `print` (Python3 syntax)

does that fit the rules?

Comment: I can't use in the task set() method and join() only use sort()

Comment: can you you copy and paste the actual rules, it doesn't make much sense

Comment: `set` is not a method

Comment: I pasted another code to my answer in the down please see.

Comment: Please rechek again. I posted text of my task. Thanks.

Comment: @EldarNecefov how about now?

Comment: those rules aren't as restrictive as you said!  it doesn't say you can _only_ use `sort` method and nothing else

Comment: good but I must input like : 4843250 and it splits variant is 4 8 5 not input like that 4 8 4 ... Now I must input with space. But I need input without space

Comment: Thanks for help. You are right I must do it myself )